# Why do I need to add new non-default inventory source to use In-store Delivery?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, multi-source-inventory

Magento docs states that [Sources represent locations storing and shipping available product stock](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/modules/inventory/manage-sources.html), and "All stores begin with a default source that must remain enabled. Single Source merchants (merchants who ship all products from one location) use the default source for their single point of inventory location and shipments.".

In Magento 2.4 we have a new feature: [In-store Delivery](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-in-store-delivery.html), which would allow our customers to have their order delivered to a specific "store source" depending on how far away it is from this source.

However, to use this feature we **must have** configured a non-default stock **and** source.
[image]

So if I have a single inventory source (let's call it *default vendor*), and a single stock (i.e.: *venue 1 store*), I cannot allow my customers to have their orders delivered at the store?

Am I getting it wrong, or it was poorly designed? Considering I got it wrong (most likely), what would be the correct way to have the above scenario configured in Magento 2.4+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply configure the flat rate method to "In-store pickup" or add a custom shipping method that you call in store pickup. The "in-store delivery" implies that you ship from a warehouse to a retail location.

Answer (score 0):

I got this in this [link](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-sources-disable.html)

> You cannot disable the Default Source. Magento uses this source for
> all new, imported products, for bundle products, and for third-party
> system support. You can enable or disable custom sources at any time.

Thanks
Happy Coding